# Selecting Images With Modal Quickview Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap template for a class project. I have everything pretty well wrapped up except for the Quickview piece. On my products page I have a list of products and each product has a quick view button. The trouble I am having is the image and description that shows up when you click on quick view is the same for all products. How do I create the quick view such that each product's quickview button brings up a quickview specific for that product? The page is located at http://capmobile.altervista.org/iphones.html.

The HTML code for the entire page is extremely long therefore I posted the link to the page. I hope that is okay as I'm not sure what piece of code to cut-n-paste here.

Thank you,

Comment: In your code only one product model is set

Comment: Where do I set the additional product models? The page currently has two iphones listed, which I'm using as testing until I get the modal sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

you missed one close div. so all divs are merge inside the first model. so you need to add one `</div>` end of the each model popup code.

```
      <div id="iphone7" class="modal fade quick-view" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
               <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <div class="media">
                  <div class="media-left">
                    <img class="media-object" src="img/products/quick-view/iphone7.jpeg" alt="Image">
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <h2>iPhone 7</h2>
                    <h3>$769</h3>
                    <p>iPhone 7All-new dual 12MP cameras. The brightest, most colorful iPhone display ever. The fastest performance and best battery life in an iPhone. Water and splash resistant.* And stereo speakers. Every bit as powerful as it looks this is iPhone 7 Plus. The iPhone 7 Plus comes in 32GB, 128GB, and 256GB. Available in Silver, Gold, Rose Gold, Black, and Jet Black.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

     </div>
```

**updated**